# How to properly check in Inno Setup which MS SQL Server version is installed on my machine?

Tags: sql, registry, inno-setup

I'm using the 64-bit installation mode and I have to check which version of MS SQL starting from MS SQL 2005 is installed on my machine.
I can do it like this:

```
if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\XXX\Tools\ClientSetup\CurrentVersion', 'CurrentVersion', RegValue) then
  SQLVERSIONINSTALLED := RegValue;
```

where XXX are different for different versions of MS SQL.
In 64-bit install mode `HKLM` relates to the 64-bit view of the registry by default. Do I have to check both the registry views using `HKLM` and `HKLM32` for versions lower than 2016? What is the safest and the most effective way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any performance problems with reading version twice (for 32/64 bit). 
Maybe you could put the versions in an array and perform checking in a loop:

```pascal
var
sqlKeys: array of string;

  sqlKeys := ['15.0', '16.0', '17.0'];

  for I := low(sqlKeys) to high(sqlKeys) do
  begin
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM32, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\' + sqlKeys[I] + '\Tools\ClientSetup\CurrentVersion', 'CurrentVersion', RegValue) then
      SQLVERSIONINSTALLED := RegValue;

    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\' + sqlKeys[I] + '\Tools\ClientSetup\CurrentVersion', 'CurrentVersion', RegValue) then
      SQLVERSIONINSTALLED := RegValue;
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using
`SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion` ?
I believe it is on XP, Win8 and Win10